# Result of document.getElementById in loop remain same

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<?php for($i=0; $i< mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++){  ?>

<table id="t01" style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th colspan="2"><?php print_r($results[$i]['arr_question']); ?></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php print_r($results[$i]['a']); ?></td>
    <td><?php print_r($results[$i]['b']); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php print_r($results[$i]['c']); ?></td>
    <td><?php print_r($results[$i]['d']); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
  <td colspan="2"><button type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('').innerHTML= '<?php print_r($results[$i]['answer']); ?>'"> Answer </button>
  <p id=''></p>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> <td colspan="2"><?php print_r($results[$i]['description']); ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</br>
<?php } ?>
```

In this code `document.getElementById('').innerHTML` is not working properly, it returns the same value while clicking on button in loop, when i put id equals `$i` it return the value in same place at every loop, it overrides the data at same place, when i put any static value it returns same. What should i do for getting the different value at different places. Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: id attribute cannot be an empty string

Comment: I don't see any ID value being passed to getElementById, nor do I see any markup which has an ID that could be passed.  Do some reading on how HTML IDs work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have empty ids, assign an id as follows:

```
 <p id='p-<?php echo $i; ?>'></p>
```

And use it as follows in the query selector:

```
<button type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('p-<?php echo $i; ?>').innerHTML= '<?php print_r($results[$i]['answer']); ?>'"> Answer </button>
```